# The Image is not fetch in the Table View IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, zappdev

Url :- https://newdrcom.azurewebsites.net/DoctorsList.aspx

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = doctorsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DoctorTableViewcellTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DoctorTableViewcellTableViewCell
        let doctor = doctorData[indexPath.row]

        cell.doctorname.text = doctor.name
        cell.doctorDepartment.text = doctor.department
        cell.doctorspeclization.text = doctor.specialization
        cell.hospitalName.text = doctor.hospital
//        cell.doctorimg.image = UIImage(named: doctor.picture ?? "")
        guard let receivedImage = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: doctorData[indexPath.row].picture ?? "")!) else {
            
            return cell
        }
        cell.doctorimg.image = UIImage(data: receivedImage)
        return cell
        }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 360
    }
}
```

Getting this error :-

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

> Synchronous URL loading of http://flspinalsurgeon.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/704ef3f5ca13ed331b597014a1f3fe7a_400x400.jpeg should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

Comment: Like the warning says, don't use a synchronous call when downloading data from a remote server. Learn about using URLSession or perhaps in this case AsyncImage.

Comment: `.picture ?? ""`, validate that you have a proper url before you try to download anything. "" is not a proper url.